# Flutter hive change field

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am creating a app in flutter and I am using Hive.

I have created some models and registered typeadapters.

```
Eg:
Normally its : create model with annotations -> run build runner -> register type adapter -> use box
```

So my question is when I have to do some changes again in model and I have to run build runner again so that fields get updated in generated adapter.
I have to remove all appdata or uninstall app so that I can store data into new structure.

The problem is every time I change a field or add a field due to previosly stored data in box ,it gives error, I have to delete the app or remove its data.

How can I make changes to model without deleting previous data.

Answer (score 3):

As from the official [documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter?id=updating-a-class) of the `Hive` package, you need just to follow those steps in order to delete, add, and update a field in your adapter:

- Don't change the field numbers for any existing fields.
- If you add new fields, any objects written by the "old" adapter can still be read by the new adapter. These fields are just ignored. Similarly, objects written by your new code can be read by your old code: the new field is ignored when parsing.
- Fields can be renamed and even changed from public to private or vice versa as long as the field number stays the same.
- Fields can be removed, as long as the field number is not used again in your updated class.
- Changing the type of a field is not supported. You should create a new one instead.
- You have to provide `defaultValue` for new non-nullable fields after enabling null safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run this command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This command will invoke the Hive code generator tool and generate the `.g.dart` files for all the annotated models in your project. The `--delete-conflicting-outputs` option is used to ensure that any outdated files are deleted before generating the new ones.

After running the command, you should see the generated `.g.dart` files in the same directory as your model classes.